# Cant pass value to another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i have navigation controller and  i want to change label text of next controller before view is loaded. There is my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ProductViewController *product = [[ProductViewController alloc]init];

    product.myDescription.text = [[self.listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:product animated:YES];

}
```

I did try product.myDescription.text = @"123"; But it still not working.. i have no idea why, maybe i missing something? myDescription is connected UILabel of my second controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myDescription` doesn't exist when you try to use it because the view hasn't been loaded yet. You can ensure the view is loaded by requesting it (`product.view`) though doing this is generally a little strange (because you aren't going to use the view). A better (but more code) approach is to pass the values required and have the controller set them when the view is loaded.

Comment: I solve this, i pass reference to string that was not attached to view... thank you Wain!